# How to change min instance of cloud run service configuration automatically at specific time everyday

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I have cloud run service running with min instance 0 set. It takes about 20 sec to start the instance and can't make it faster than that.

Also I don't want to keep CPU always ON and set min instance to 1 to avoid higher cost.

I am looking for an option where let's say at specific time in the morning cloud run service config can automatically change to min instance 1 and at night time it changes back to 0.

I think this can be achieveble using creating cloud function to make this change and using cloud scheduler trigger this function. But have little exprience with these services so looking for some template or examples.

just created cloud run hello world service

Comment: You would need to write that yourself. You could use Cloud Scheduler calling Cloud Functions or Cloud Run with a function/application you write to modify the Cloud Run instance.

Comment: In the near future, you will be able to update the service scalability without redeploying a  new revision. Today, you must deploy a whole new revision and it could be painful. In any case, you must write code to achieve those operation.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere ... I think you could have 2 revisions, one with the 'day' config and one with the 'night' config, and then just flip the % traffic against each service from 0 to 100, and vice-versa. I haven't tested this though.

Comment: Traffic splitting is also cumbersome to use. I chatted with the eng team and they will implement a PATCH feature on Cloud Run to be able to patch only the part of the config that you want without repeating all the service description (as today). No ETA but simplification in the future!